# Is there a restriction for mediaplayers?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to store numerous instances of mediaplayers, i.e I load new music file to a new instance of a mediaplayer and store it in `arraylist` by loading it first from Assets using `AssetFileDescriptor`.
After a few files loaded (about 7) I'm starting to get `IOException setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000`, I've checked the files multiple times, switched their places, and the error still persists. But if I load less than 7 files everything works fine.

Now my question is, how to get around this problem? Am I doing it the right way or maybe there is an option to load all the sounds into a single instance of `mediaplayer` without using `HashMaps` and `ArrayLists`?

Comment: Are you trying to play the files consecutively? This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781522/playing-audio-files-one-after-another

Comment: @krsteeve, unfortunately no. I'm trying to load all of the files into memory one after another as a separate instance of the media player.

Comment: Can you give more details about the effect you are trying to achieve?