# Background music won't play automatically on App start?

Tags: android

Apologize if this question has been repeated 1000 times before, but I'm stuck really and need the help :/.

**[PROBLEM]**

`QUESTION 1: Where in the coding I need to add or change to make my background music play automatically when app starts?` As it is now I can only make it play by using a START button and it also plays across my other activities which is also what I want it to do.

`QUESTION 2: If I want more than one music file to be played, what should be implemented?` (I know I need to create a new question for this, but just thought if it possible to combine these two into one Q, that would be easier).

.

**MusicService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mrkrabs);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }//onStartCommand ends here


    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return super.stopService(name);
    }//stopService ends here


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }//onDestroy ends here


}//MyService ends here
```

.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button stopMusic;
    Button startMusic;
    Button nextActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stopMusic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopMusic);
        stopMusic.setOnClickListener(this);

        startMusic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startMusic);
        startMusic.setOnClickListener(this);

        nextActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        nextActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
    }//onCreate ends here


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.stopMusic:
                stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                stopMusic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startMusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case R.id.startMusic:
                startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                startMusic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stopMusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case R.id.nextActivity:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
                break;
        }//switch ends here
    }//onClick ends here


}//MainActivity ends here
```

.

**Manifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.musicapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
        <activity android:name=".NextActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: 1. just start your service from application class to play music when app starts.

2. do you want to play all music file at the same time or do you want to play them in sequence?

Comment: @Techierj: 1. Yes but if I change activity it will stop playing the background music, won't it? 2. I would like the music to be played in sequence indeed.

Comment: No, it won't stop on changing activity.
for the second question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781522/playing-audio-files-one-after-another) will help you.

Comment: Niiice! Such a silly mistake. Thanks for the help @Techierj. I'll look at the link you sent me regarding sequential playing. Hopefully it won't be any hard reading as I'm new to Android.

Comment: yuppp. go ahead :) and don't forget to upvote comment :D

Comment: @Techierj: hehe, done! :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Mak sure you properly creating the media player, setting source, prepare/loop calls in service.
   [Refer this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm)
2. You can use [ServiceConnection](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/02/binding-service-using-ibinder-and.html?m=1) in your activity and pass sources and change sources from your activity. That's what the typical music application does.

[Here is the universal music player code you can refer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/tree/master/mobile/src/main)

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, much appreciated. I have another question, how do I implement onPause so that the music pauses instead of stopping and restarting? @albeee