# Playing a sound after a loop is complete

Tags: android, loops

I want to play sound from raw folder when button clicked with this schema

First opening sounds, then sounds from letter from edittext, and last closing sounds,

But i just play first file,

This is my onClick codes

```
int[] openSound ={R.raw.ding,R.raw.open};
int[] closeSound ={R.raw.close,R.raw.dong};
int[] myMusic;
String editTextValue = yourEditText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
final int length = editTextValue.length();
int[] myMusic = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
char letter = editTextValue.charAt(i);
myMusic[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(letter), "raw", getPackageName());}
PlayMedia playOpen = new PlayMedia(MainActicity,openSound);
playOpen.execute();

PlayMedia playAudio = new PlayMedia(MainActivity.this,myMusic);
playAudio.execute();

PlayMedia playClose = new PlayMedia(MainActivity.this,closeSound);
playClose.execute();
```

Comment: This my PlayMedia class from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781522/playing-audio-files-one-after-another

Comment: Could it be that the successive play instructions do not wait for the initial one to execute? I suggest you add the whole `PlayMedia` class in the question. You need to leverage on `OnCompletionListener` and play the sounds in successions.

Comment: Can you give an example codes, my English not to good to understand it,

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question is to join all the int[], then play it with PlayMedia

```
int[] concatenate = combine(array1, array2);
    PlayMedia playAudio = new PlayMedia(MainActivity.this, concatenate);
    playAudio.execute();

}


public static int[] combine(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c){
    int length = openSound.length + myMusic.length+closeSound.length;
    int[] result = new int[length];
    System.arraycopy(openSound, 0, result, 0, openSound.length);
    System.arraycopy(myMusic, 0, result, openSound.length, myMusic.length);
    System.arraycopy(closeSound, 0, result, openSound.length+myMusic.length, closeSound)
    return result;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It won't work, unless you add a callback to **completion** events.

You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html), and an example:

```
  yourPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
             // Here add the execute of the next audio, +
             // and another callback if you want to concatenate more.
        }
    });
```